# CordovaError: Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Hey guys i am getting this error even after setting the java_Home environement varibale, could you please help me. The first image is for the environement variable named PATH; the second is my java_home environement variable

[image: THIS IS THE path ENVIRONNEMENT VARIABLE]

[image]

Comment: Did you close and reopen the windows after adding JAVA_HOME?

Comment: i closed the terminal then i reopened it and nothing happens